# Postfix and Altermime config. Send html emails with disclaimer

Tags: html, dovecot, postfix-mta

I am currently running a Centos 7 instance. Already installed: postfix, dovecot, altermime. Sending and receiving emails works fine. However, what I am trying to do is attach a disclaimer for every mail sent.

My problem is in the disclaimer config there is a disclaimer text option, and a disclaimer html. But my email is always sent as plain text, so I receive emails with a disclaimer showing html tags.

How can i configure postfix or altermime to send html emails, or send a plain text with an image attached?

Here's my disclaimer config:

```
from_address=`grep -m 1 "From:" in.$$ | cut -d "<" -f 2 | cut -d ">" -f 1`

if [ `grep -wi ^${from_address}$ ${DISCLAIMER_ADDRESSES}` ]; then
  /usr/bin/altermime --input=in.$$ \
                   --disclaimer-html=/etc/postfix/disclaimer.html \
                   --disclaimer=/etc/postfix/disclaimer.txt \
                   --force-for-bad-html \
                   --xheader="X-Copyrighted-Material: Please visit http://www.company.com/privacy.h$
                    { echo Message content rejected; exit $EX_UNAVAILABLE; }
fi
```

I've tried adding the html text in disclaimer.txt, or in disclaimer.html. The email is always received as plain text showing the html tags.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.